# Can I attach a VM to NIC through an arm template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template, azure-vm-templates

When I tried doing this with portal I could achieve it from virtual machine networking ..
I wanted to know if it works with either NIC or VM arm-template .I tried the both and they failed.
1.Network profile - Networking ID
2.Virtual Machine -ID

Comment: Do you want to attach a NIC to an existing VM with a template?

Comment: yes. @NancyXiong-MSFT

Comment: Can you expand on your scenario - are you trying to attach a secondary nic (new) or replace the primary nic?

Comment: I wanted to attach a secondary nic to an existing vm (which has a primary nic already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot attach an existing or a new NIC and attach to the existing VM through template. There is no property of NIC to achieve it. You just can create a VM and attach an existing or new NIC to it. For more details about template of NIC, see [Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/networkinterfaces).

Comment: .Is there any property of Virtual Machine that does this job as an extension -@Charles

Comment: Xu -MSFT  Can this be achieved through VM template as an extension?

Comment: @twinklehema It seems you cannot achieve that through vm extension. The vm xtension just provide post-deployment configuration and automation tasks on Azure VMs. For more, see [Azure virtual machine extensions and features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/overview). But NIC is a resource on Azure.

Comment: how can I attach existing NIC to a new VM using ARM template? I could not find any property for that. Can you help me.